# Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is not an integer.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm sure this is a very simple proof but I can't seem to get it right. I tried to do it by induction but get stuck trying to show that $\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)}$ is not an integer and also cannot seem to do it through other methods. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Presumably, you don't define $\mathbb N$ as including $0$...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Despite being about $n\in\Bbb{N}$, induction doesn't work too great here.

Instead, how about trying to identify the nearest integers... in particular, you should be able to show
$$n<\sqrt{n(n+1)}<n+1$$
for $n\in\Bbb{N}$

Comment: Neat approach. I was going to suggest appealing to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic but this is even better.

Comment: Oh wow didn't see it was that simple, thanks so much!!

Comment: Great approach. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Related approach: If $n(n+1)$ is a square, then $4(n^2+n)=4n^2+4n$ is a square. But so is $4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$. The difference of two square is $1$ when...

Answer (score 2):

$(n+1)^2 > n(n+1) > n^2$ taking square roots $n+1 > \sqrt{n(n+1)} > n$, and there is no integer between $n$ and $n+1$.